# How to return multiple model object returns with spring annotations?

Tags: spring

I am converting my controllers to annotated style controllers in spring mvc.

Basically I do this in the old style controller simpleformcontroller.

```
protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception { 
    Map referenceData = new HashMap(); 
     List<ItemVo> lstItem1 = eqrManager .searchAllEqptCondQualItems("A1", "BOXES");     List<ItemVo> lstItem2 = eqrManager.searchAllEqptFullQualItems("A2", "CANNED_GOODS");     referenceData.put("BOX_ITEMS", lstItem1);
referenceData.put("CANNED_ITEMS", lstItem2); 
return referenceData; 
}
```

I do below way by taking  model as a input argument,But it is calling only one time,How can i make below method should call everytime when form submission happens.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET) public void setUp(Model model) {  
   model.addAttribute("CANNED_ITEMS", eqrManager.searchAllEqptFullQualItems("A2", "CANNED_GOODS"))          .addAttribute("BOX_ITEMS", eqrManager.searchAllEqptCondQualItems("A1", "BOXES")); }
```

Regards,

Raj

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@ModelAttribute`-annotated method as a replacement of `referenceData()`:

```
@ModelAttribute("CANNED_ITEMS")
public List<ItemVo> cannedItems() {
    return eqrManager.searchAllEqptFullQualItems("A2", "CANNED_GOODS");
}

@ModelAttribute("BOX_ITEMS")
public List<ItemVo> boxItems() {
    return eqrManager .searchAllEqptCondQualItems("A1", "BOXES");
}
```

These methods are called automatically for each request handled by the controller where they're defined, and their results are addded to the model.

Comment: How can i call this in single method with every form submission.

Comment: I tried that before its working,But i want to define single method returning all my iniital objects to load my form,it should call every request.